# ASP.NET Identity 2, enforce email domain when adding users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Is there a setting to allow only emails from one certain domain, when register users in ASP.NET Identity 2?

Comment: No specific setting, you but can always check yourself if email has the correct domain name before creating a user.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been a good setting.

Comment: Not really. Very easy to do yourself in your own code, very costly to make a part of a framework. I'd rather Microsoft concentrated on more complex problems

Comment: Well there are built in settings for password or rules, it would not be hard to do that yourself either. One of the benifits with this framework is that its out of the box, just plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regular expression or a custom code to validate only emails from a specific domain..
You can see an example here:
https://techbrij.com/asp-net-core-identity-login-email-username

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was hoping for a built in setting.

Comment: I ended up with a regex solution. Made a class inheriting the UserValidator<TUser,string> and overriding the ValidateAsync.